# How to make the .php and .html extension invisible of a page when clicking the page from the menu bar?

Tags: php

I have a website with a menu. When clicking on any of the pages in the menu it should go to the particular page whether it is `page.php` or `page.html` but it should not show the `.php` and `.html` in the url. How can I achieve this?

I have written a piece of code in htaccess. But it is not working.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a php question, but rather an apache question.
You have the right idea in that you need to use the .htaccess file for this.

However, don't forget to make sure that the RewriteEngine is set to ON, and to have the parameters at the end inside [ ] brackets.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

You can read more about this [here](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)

Comment: RewriteEngine on



RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

Comment: I have written the code which you have given but it is not working.